# How do I validate an email field and then reset it after submission?

Tags: jquery, html, forms, validation, reset

I have a form that has 2 issues:

**1.** The email field is accepting any text.. but I need it to accept only valid emails

**2.** I need the fields to be reset to blank after successful submission.

You can see the demo site [here](http://taskbasket.net/public/demo.html)  (click the "Click Here" link)

**Here is the form:**

```
<form method="post" action="submit.php" id="contactform" class="signin">


        <input name="email" id="email" type="text" class="feedback-input" placeholder="Email" required pattern="[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+(?:[A-Z]{2}|com|org|net|edu|gov|mil|biz|info|mobi|name|aero|asia|jobs|museum)" />
       <div class="antispam">
       <br /><input name="url" type="hidden" /></div>
       <textarea name="message" id="message" class="feedback-input" placeholder="Write away!" required></textarea>
        <button id="flybutton">
            <p>Ready, Aim... </p>
            <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 512 512" enable-background="new 0 0 512 512" xml:space="preserve">
                <path id="paper-plane-icon" d="M462,54.955L355.371,437.187l-135.92-128.842L353.388,167l-179.53,124.074L50,260.973L462,54.955z
M202.992,332.528v124.517l58.738-67.927L202.992,332.528z"></path>
            </svg>
        </button>
</form>
```

Currently when a user clicks the submit button, it calls on the following scripts to do the submitting. How do I incorporate a reset function (to delete field contents) *AFTER* successful submission?

**Note:**  The form should only successfully submit if the email is in the proper format.

Right now the form keeps sending me blank submissions, and I can't figure it out!

**Here are the scripts:**

```
 <script>
        var $btn = $('#flybutton');
        $("#contactform").validate({
            submitHandler: function (form) {
                fly(form);
            }
        });

        $btn.on('fliyingEnd', function (e, form) {

            $('#mask').fadeOut(300);
            $("#login-box").fadeOut(300); 
        })



        function fly(form){

            $btn.toggleClass('clicked');
            $btn.find('p').text(function(i, text) {
                return text === "Fire!" ? "Fire!" : "Fire!";
            });

            setTimeout(function () {
                $btn.trigger('fliyingEnd', [form]);
            }, 1000);

        }
    </script>
```

and

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

  /* Attach a submit handler to the form */
$("#contactform").submit(function(event) {

    /* Stop form from submitting normally */
    event.preventDefault();

    /* Clear result div*/
    $("#result").html('');

    /* Get some values from elements on the page: */
    var values = $(this).serialize();

    /* Send the data using post and put the results in a div */
    $.ajax({
        url: "submit.php",
        type: "post",
        data: values,

    });
});
});
</script>
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Problably the form already has the default event attached. Try to do `off("submit").on("submit", [your custom code])`. And put a `return false` when you do not want the default behavior.

Comment: Appreciate the feedback, but where would I include that off("submit")... etc..in which scripts do I add this?  And what would be my custom code?  I'm very new to this, thank you

Comment: Current you have `$("#contactform").submit(...`, you should try `$("#contactform")..off("submit").submit(...`. And put a `return false;` when you want to cancel the submission.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm super new and don't really know when is the correct time to cancel the submission.  I can replace  $("#contactform").submit(... with  $("#contactform").off("submit").submit(... but where exactly do I put return false; can you provide an example? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

> The email field is accepting any text.. but I need it to accept only valid emails

Since you want an email, and not any text, you can set the type of the input field from `text`, to `email` and combined with your pattern, the browser will handle the validity check. However, you should do a validity check in the backend as well.

Reference : https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input

> I need the fields to be reset to blank after successful submission.

An easy way to do that, since you are using JQuery's `$.ajax()`, is the following

```
$.ajax({
    url: "submit.php",
    type: "post",
    data: values,
}).success(function() {
    document.querySelector('#email').value = '';
    document.querySelector('#message').value = '';
}).error(function () {
    //something to handle failure to successfully submit
});
```

What will this do:

It will send the request, and if the request is successful, it will call an anonymous function that resets the input fields' values to nothing. If the request fails for some reason it will do something else that you'll decide.

Reference : http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Some side notes:

```
/* Clear result div*/
$("#result").html('');
```

As far as we can tell from your snippets there is no `#result` element in there. Maybe you have it in your full code, so ignore this.

```
$("#contactform").validate({
    submitHandler: function (form) {
        fly(form);
    }
});
```

As far as I know `$().validate()` is not a jquery method, maybe you should look at that?

Comment: Thanks Mitch! Switching the input type to "email" worked perfectly. As for the ajax request, I've found another solution which refreshes the page which works fine too. However, my form keeps sending my blank emails, so I'm wondering how to implement "back-end" protection. My php file has a form handler like this:  if($_POST && isset($_POST['email'], $_POST['message'])) { but I keep getting blank emails occasionally or MULTIPLE emails containing the same data. What gives?

Comment: Hm, since the email field is `required` and since I suppose your browser supports HTML5, the form should not get submitted. But I think I know what happens. You actually override the default behaviour, by doing `event.preventDefault();` (as you should) in the `.submit()` callback, so while the browser normally _would not_ submit the form without passing the validation check you imposed, by preventing that behaviour, it sends the form anyway simply when you click the submit button. Maybe you should add a validation test in the `.submit()` callback or think of another way to do it alltogether

Comment: Also, regarding PHP's `isset()`, passing it an empty string will evaluate to `true`, so, there's that. Reference : http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php
@JasonCampbell

Comment: Cool, thanks Mitch. I'm just a little confused as to how to add a validation test to the .submit() callback. Could you provide a brief example or a link?  I'm assuming you mean adding something within this script:  $("#contactform").submit(function(event) {

....

Comment: @JasonCampbell yes, that's the part of the script I am talking about. You could do 2 checks in there, immediately after `event.preventDefault();` . I am not going to tell you exactly how to implement them, just what to do. First of all, you could check whether the value of the email field is not empty. If it is, you should `return` to stop further execution. After that, and if it's not an empty string, you could test the value against the regular expression you are using in your email `input`. If it is a match, proceed, else do a `return` to stop further execution.

Answer (score 0):

as long as you are using jquery for submittion , you can use this wonderful plugin http://jqueryvalidation.org/

it saves a lot of time writing regular expression functions to validate each field plus it have its own ajax method